# How to use results from list widget in another class?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I am new to object oriented programming and need assistance getting the value from a listwidget in one class to another class. I have one listwidget called selectedVariables in the MainWindow class. I want the SecondWindow class to be able to get the variables from selectedVariables so the user can select them in the second window to group the data by a certain variable. Ideally, when they click the three dots, a new window pops up with a list of the widgets, but for now I just need to understand how to get the selectedVariable list items and send it to the SecondWindow Class. The code below runs without errors, but has no reference to the selectedVariables list.

I did try layout.addWidget(MainWindow.selectedVariables, 3, 0, 1, 1) and it gave me the error :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "S:\1WORKING\FINANCIAL ANALYST\Shawn Schreier\Python\Minimum Example.py", line 99, in 
mw = MainWindow()

File "S:\1WORKING\FINANCIAL ANALYST\Shawn Schreier\Python\Minimum Example.py", line 49, in **init**
self.mw = SecondWindow()

File "S:\1WORKING\FINANCIAL ANALYST\Shawn Schreier\Python\Minimum Example.py", line 30, in **init**
layout.addWidget(MainWindow.selectedVariables, 3, 0, 1, 1)

AttributeError: type object 'MainWindow' has no attribute 'selectedVariables'

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QListWidget, QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QFileDialog, QTabWidget, QCheckBox
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSettings
import inspect
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QGridLayout()
        by = QLabel("By")
        byVariables = QLineEdit()
        byVariableList = QListWidget()
        layout.addWidget(by, 1,0,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(byVariables, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        byButton = QPushButton("...")
        layout.addWidget(byButton, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Add a title
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI Querying Program")

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.initUI()
        self.setButtonConnections()
        
        self.mw = SecondWindow()
        

    def initUI(self):
        subLayouts = {}

        subLayouts['LeftColumn'] = QGridLayout()
    
        self.layout.addLayout(subLayouts['LeftColumn'],1)
        
        # Buttons
        self.buttons = {}
        self.buttons['addVariable'] = QPushButton('>')
        self.buttons['removeVariable'] = QPushButton('<')
        self.buttons['Toolkit'] = QPushButton('Toolkit')
        
        
        self.variables = QListWidget()
        self.selectedVariables = QListWidget()
        
        subLayouts['LeftColumn'].addWidget(self.variables, 7,0,4,1)
        subLayouts['LeftColumn'].addWidget(self.selectedVariables, 7,1,4,1)
        subLayouts['LeftColumn'].addWidget(self.buttons['addVariable'], 10,0,1,1)
        subLayouts['LeftColumn'].addWidget(self.buttons['removeVariable'], 10,1,1,1)
        subLayouts['LeftColumn'].addWidget(self.buttons['Toolkit'], 11,1,1,1)
        
        names = ['apple', 'banana', 'Cherry']
        self.variables.insertItems(0, names)
        
    def setButtonConnections(self):
        self.buttons['addVariable'].clicked.connect(self.add_variable)
        self.buttons['removeVariable'].clicked.connect(self.remove_variable)
        self.buttons['Toolkit'].clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)   
        
    def add_variable(self):
        selected_elements=[item.text() for item in self.variables.selectedItems()]
        variableItem = self.selectedVariables.insertItems(self.variables.count(),selected_elements)
        #self.variablesSearch.clear()
        
    def remove_variable(self):
        oldVariable = self.selectedVariables.currentRow()
        self.selectedVariables.takeItem(oldVariable)
    
    def show_new_window(self):
        self.mw.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication([])
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    # Run the app
    app.exec()
    app.quit()
    #sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Do you want to *move* those items to the second window, or copy them?

Comment: I want to copy them. Basically, on the first window, they select all the variables they want in the first window. In the second window they will do some analysis (Median, sum, etc) and I want them to choose how to do the grouping using one of the variables they selected on the first screen.

Comment: @musicamante if you have any tutorials or anything that can help I'd appreciate it as my program is much more complex than the simple example. I've created the second window, which includes a button. This button actually opens a third window with the list elements you helped me with. Right now, I've gotten relatively close, but am still struggling with the third window, so any tutorials or thoughts that can help me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *copy* items, then you should use the [`clone()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#clone) function of QListWidgetItem.

Note that you should do the same also in `add_variable`: while your case is very simple, *cloning* an item ensures that **all** its properties (including custom data, like text or background color) are copied, not only its text.

```py
class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)

        by = QLabel("By")
        byVariables = QLineEdit()
        self.byVariableList = QListWidget()
        byButton = QPushButton("...")
        layout.addWidget(by, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(byVariables, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(byButton, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.byVariableList, 3, 0, 1, 2)

    def setItems(self, items):
        self.byVariableList.clear()
        for item in items:
            self.byVariableList.addItem(item)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    # ...
    def add_variable(self):
        for item in self.variables.selectedItems():
            self.selectedVariables.addItem(item.clone())

    def show_new_window(self):
        items = []
        for i in range(self.selectedVariables.count()):
            items.append(self.selectedVariables.item(i).clone())
        self.mw.setItems(items)
        self.mw.show()
```

<sup>Note that when `app.exec()` returns, it means that the application has been quit, calling `app.quit()` after that is pointless. Also: 1. rows and columns of a grid layout are always based on 0-indexes (just like almost *anything* in computing), so you should add items from 0, not 1; 2. the row/column span always defaults to 1, so there is no point in specifying it unless you specifically want a span greater than 1.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This helped me get to where I need to be. My actual code is much more complex but this guides me on the right track. Could you summarize the necessary steps to do this in most situations? It seems like the approach is to create a new window, instantiate the new window in the main window, create a method in each window to pass the data between them? Does that sum it up, or did I miss anything? I'm going to need many windows and passing data between them, so I appreciate any advice/thoughts or tutorials you can share. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShawnSchreier There are no general rules for any situation. It all depends on the program structure. For instance, if there is a clear hierarchy of windows, then the third window would be probably created only in the second (but you should also opt for QDialog instead of simple QWidgets, to take advantage of the window modality and its event loop) similarly to what alexpdev did answering your other question, but if those windows might exist and even work independently as well, then a "main" controller (which in most cases would be the "main window") is preferred, similarly to what done above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the SecondWindow, class a child class.  That means, making it inherit your MainWindow methods. Like this

```
Class SecondWindow(MainWindow):
```

And from what i understood, from your code the selectedVariables instance is interchangeable according to the utilized methods. So it would be wiser to define it as a instance variable in your constructor

```
Class MainWindow(Qwidget):
   def__init__(self):
      self.selectedVariables = QListWidget()
```

That way, it will be easier for you to inherit independently what action happens to it . Also you wont need to call the method everytime so kinda of a must.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. With the first part, is that considered multiple inheritance? I am very new but the book I am reading really frowned upon that so I wasn't sure if I could do it. With the second part of your response, can you explain the benefits or how that works a little more? Thanks!

Comment: Well it doesnt have to be, it can be only one inheritance(since you will be inheriting the Qwidget class nonetheless). I think, the reason in your book it is frowned upon, is mostly because sometimes you inherit unwanted methods and instances. Which can be a bother in big medium project, but that wouldnt apply to your case nonetheless. Since you only have two classes. The benefits are pretty simple, it gives the idea in your code that the variable, will be used in multiple methods. And also, when you inherit, the actions done on it. Will be renembered in the classes that inherit it.

Comment: Also it fixes your issue so yeah.

Comment: The code I have is kind of a minimum example and will have many more classes. I just wanted to keep it relatively simple so hopefully someone can help me. I've tried making the change you made above and run into the following issues - if I establish the SecondWindow first, it says the MainWindow is not defined. Then, if I move the SecondWindow down to the bottom, it crashes my kernel in spyder/jupyter notebook. I haven't tried any any other editors yet. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well if you are moving, your secondWindow class, after the check if the code is running in this module statement  (if __name__ == "__main__":), it will certainly crash i am not sure how down you moved. The secondWindow class. When it comes to the ide, i am not sure why you are using jupyter notebook in that matter. Since it doesnt relate well to oop. But hey you can so the ide is not to blame

Comment: Also of course, you will need to make sure the inheritance, of the instance is applyable to all cases. So utilizing a dunder method, so other methods inherit it  will be a must  def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.selectedVariables, attr)

Comment: I really don't use jupyter, I was just trying a second ide to see if it was a spyder issue with it crashing. I just moved the SecondWindow down below all of the code associated with the MainWindow class, but above the if __name__ line of code.